# AngularJs loading error. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAppRv due to

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. I am trying to make some work in my project. But got an error which is very common as I search in google and lot of people got the same error. I tried every way but unable to solve.
Little difference here is that, at first time when I start server I do not get the error, When I refresh the page then I get the error. Can any one suggest me by seeing my code? I am sharing my codes below.

Error in console:

```
angular.js:116 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAppRv due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myAppRv' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/nomod?p0=myAppRv
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:116:12
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:2303:17
    at ensure (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:2224:38)
    at module (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:2301:14)
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4999:22
    at forEach (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:408:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4983:5)
    at createInjector (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4900:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:1955:20)
    at bootstrap (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:1976:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myAppRv&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'myAppRv'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.9%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyAppRv%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A116%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A2303%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A2224%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A2301%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A4999%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A408%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A4983%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A4900%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A1955%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A1976%3A12)
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:116:12
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:2303:17
    at ensure (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:2224:38)
    at module (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:2301:14)
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4999:22
    at forEach (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:408:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4983:5)
    at createInjector (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4900:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:1955:20)
    at bootstrap (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:1976:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myAppRv&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'myAppRv'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.9%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyAppRv%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A116%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A2303%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A2224%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A2301%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A4999%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A408%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A4983%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A4900%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A1955%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.6%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A1976%3A12)
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:116:12
    at http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:5023:15
    at forEach (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:408:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4983:5)
    at createInjector (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:4900:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:1955:20)
    at bootstrap (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:1976:12)
    at angularInit (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:1861:5)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/angular.js:34354:5)
    at j (http://192.168.1.6:3000/js/jquery.min.js:2:27136)
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myAppRv">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="img/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">    
</head>
<body>


   <div ng-controller="myDashCtrl">
      <h2>Hello, <span>{{userName}}</span></h2>
      <select ng-model="selectedClient" ng-options="x.inv_name for x in clientDetails">
      </select>
   </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/framework7/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sortable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highstock.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chart.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/landing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/comparision.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rangeslider.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
</body>
```

my-app.js

```
 var appc = angular.module("myAppRv", []);
 appc.controller("myDashCtrl", function($scope) {

$$.get(curr_ip+'app_url/index', function (client_data_ajax) {
  var client_data=JSON.parse(client_data_ajax);
  console.log("...................................................");

  console.log(client_data);

  $scope.userName = client_data.name;
  alert($scope.userName);
  $scope.clientDetails = client_data.client;

  console.log($scope.clientDetails);

  console.log("...................................................");

});
});
```

Comment: There are not so many reasons why this error may appear. Since the obvious one can be ruled out, the question cannot gain a certain answer. There's no guarantee that js/my-app.js is loaded properly. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem - a fiddle, plunk, stackblitz, etc.

Comment: But I can not understand that when I restart server it works, but after refresh the page the error shows.

Comment: What is the server? Is routing used? Did you post the whole app?

Comment: I am using phonegap. Trying to create mobile app using framework7. No routing is used till now.

Comment: Make sure that js/my-app.js is served properly. Try to open it by url. Replace all urls with absolute paths. i.e. /js/my-app.js instead of js/my-app.js . Try to temporarily disable jQuery (plugins that depend on it reasonably won't load), it can affect the way how AngularJS compiles the document. Try to move all <script> to <head> and move l ng-app="myAppRv" from <html> to <body>. That's all that comes to mind, hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, Thank , I will try.